# Is there a python itertools way of generating this data?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have the following function:

```
def e(w):
    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(w-1):
            for k in range(w-2):
                yield [i,j,k]
```

`print([i for i in e(4)])` generates data like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1],
 [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], 
 [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], 
 [3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 0], [3, 2, 1]]
```

I have generalised e() into a recursive function, f() :

```
def f(w, mx=0, depth=0, values=[]):
    if mx==0:
        yield values
    for i in range(w - depth):
        yield from f(w, mx-1, depth+1, values + [i])
```

`print([i for i in f(4,3)])` generates the same data.
Can this sort of data be generated using a standard library like itertools or numpy for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generalise to arbitrary depth, you can use `itertools.product` on a sequence of iterables generated by a comprehension:

```
import itertools

def combs(w, depth):
    # Returns an iterator object which yields the combinations
    return itertools.product(*(range(w-n) for n in range(depth)))

print(list(combs(4,3)))
```

which outputs (format tidied up to match yours):

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1),
(1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1),
(2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1),
(3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I completely support the policy, and indeed try to track down ChatGPT-generated answers. I didn't use ChatGPT for this answer, or indeed any answer I've ever posted here - it would be 100% against my beliefs on this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```py
import itertools

print(list(itertools.product(range(4), range(3), range(2))))

[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1),
 (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1),
 (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1),
 (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1)]
```

This also can be generalized:

```py
def generate(n):
    return list(itertools.product(*(range(i) for i in range(n, 1, -1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you generating Cartesian product? If so, search for "Cartesian product" should lead you to [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

def generate_data(w):
    return product(range(w), range(w-1), range(w-2))

print(list(generate_data(4)))
```

which outputs the same values (with difference of using tuples instead of lists):

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), 
 (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), 
 (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), 
 (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1)]
```